# Django template does not render CSS and Javascript

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have the following folder structure for my project.

```
-App1
-App2
-App3
-App4
-static
    -css
       -bootstrap.css
    -js
       -bootstrap.js
       -jquery.js
-tempaltes
     -base.html
```

Now, in my base.html file i have

But, when i view the file the css and javascript does not seem to be loaded on the page. 
In my, i have

**settings.py**

```
 TEMPLATE_DIRS = "Absolute-path-to-base.html"

 STATIC_URL = '/static'
 STATICFILES_DIRS = 'Absolute-path-to-the above static folder'
```

As per all the docs and posts what i understood was, we need to keep all the staticfiles in one place, viz, static folder in my case...and all the templates (including base.html) in one place. After doing so, i open the base.html in my browser to view the page...and it does not display the CSS and the javascript. Instead when i place the file (base.html) in the static folder things work fine.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace

```
STATIC_URL = '/static'
```

by :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

and in django templates, you should use

```
<script src="{% static "path" %}"></script>
```

also add `{% load staticfiles %}` at the top

Comment: yea i figured out that it was the way i specified my path to the script tag. Thanks anyways!